# Which is more better Firebase using Query or using Normal Reference

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I noticed there are 2 types to retrieve a user data. Which one is better?

```
firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
usersDbRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Users");

//Using Query
Query userQuery = usersDbRef.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(userUid);


//Using Normal
DatabaseReference dbRefUser = usersDbRef.child(userUid);

//And then get user name and etc...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using the following line of code:

```
usersDbRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Users");
```

You are getting all users that exist within `Users` node without any limitations.

If you are using a query, you can add limitations and ordering to your items. For example, let's say you have a node that contains 1000 items. For sure you won't use a simple reference because getting 1000 items at once, will be a waste of bandwidth and resources, since no users are interested in 1000 items. What you can do instead is to add a call to `limit(50)` and display only 50 items. So a query is needed to filter results and according to the use-case of your app, you can use one or the other in your project.

When using:

```
DatabaseReference dbRefUser = usersDbRef.child(userUid);
```

You tell Firebase that you are interested only in a single user object. So in this case, these is no need for a query, a simple reference will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Former requires you to pass `col name`

> Query userQuery = usersDbRef.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(userUid);

If `col name` is wrong, guess what happens?

```
//Yeah... you guessed right
NullpointerException: Attempt to invoke (.equalTo) on a null object reference
```

On the other end

> DatabaseReference dbRefUser = usersDbRef.child(userUid);

```
//If the user userUid exist or not, you get a valid or empty ref object without an exception
```

> Now you do the choosing